# Symfony annotation routing order

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-routing, symfony-4.3

I'm currently stuck with routing in my Symfony4 (4.3) project. My problem is pretty simple, I want to use route annotations in my controllers but I want to defined the order of these one.

For example, if I have two controllers with following routing :

```
class BarController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test/{data}", name="app_bar")
     */
    public function index($data)
    {
        // ...
        return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
            'data' => $data,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and

```
class FooController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test/my_value", name="app_foo")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // ...
        return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
            'data' => 'my_value',
        ]);
    }
}
```

In `config/routes/annotations.yaml` I define my route like this

```
app_controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

Then if I call `/test/my_value` I would like to be redirected to `FooController` since his `index` action define `@Route("/test/my_value", name="app_foo")` but like routes is loaded alphabetically the `index` action from `BarController` with `app_bar` route is called first.

So I have tried to defined following routing :

```
app_foo_controller:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/FooController.php
    type: annotation
app_controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

But this didn't work, BarController and his `app_bar` route still called before `app_foo` route from FooController.

Also, I don't understand the purpose of `config/routes/annotations.yaml` vs `config/routes.yaml` since both could contains any type of routes... I miss something ?

Comment: I would personally try and avoid a url structure where the same path sections are served by different controllers. If you do it that way around you can define the order w/o yaml files by just ordering the methods accordingly

Comment: In my case I can't use the same controller because I have too many methods relies to specific case (`/add/{generic_case}` and `/add/specific1`, `/add/specific2`, ... `/add/specific1000` so I prefer put the specific actions in specific controller) , but yes indeed it's more simple to order actions in the same controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I found the solution. I just miss the fact that I override my specifically `app_foo_controller` routing when I define `app_controllers` the solution is to defined each controllers like that :

```
app_controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
app_foo_controller:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/FooController.php
    type: annotation
app_bar_controller:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/BarController.php
    type: annotation
```

Comment: another option would be to add condition on `BarController` route so it does not get triggered, and `config/routes/annotations.yaml` is nothing more than sugar for keeping the structure more clear, it's not for functional point of view, you can name it anything you want